# Dart Global class returning Null list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, global

```
class Cart {
  static final Cart _instance = Cart._internal();
  List<Food>  _listOfFood = [];
  factory Cart([List food])  => _instance;

  Cart._internal() {
     this._listOfFood = [];
}
void  addItems(Food food) {
 print(this.listOfFood);
 }
```

when I select the "addItems" it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you try to achieve with this code sample:

1. It seems that you are implementing a Singleton design pattern, but you provide a parameter to your factory. What do you expect to happen when you have the following code?

```dart
final cart1 = Cart();
cart1.addItems(food1);
cart2.addItems(food2);
final cart2 = Cart([food3, food4]);
```

What does the cart contain now?

2. Why do you initialize the `_listOfFood` to `[]` twice?
3. Your method `void addItems(Food food)` (that should probably be called `addItem` or `addFood`) does nothing besides printing the list. So, yes, it returns nothing.

---

Here is a Minimal Working Example of such a Cart Singleton class:

```dart
void main() {
  final cart1 = Cart();
  cart1.addFood(Food(name: 'banana'));
  cart1.addFood(Food(name: 'apple'));
  cart1.addFood(Food(name: 'orange'));
  final cart2 = Cart();
  cart2.addFood(Food(name: 'mango'));
  print(cart1); // Your cart contains: banana, apple, orange, mango
  print(cart2); // Your cart contains: banana, apple, orange, mango
}

class Cart {

  static final Cart _instance = Cart._internal();
  
  List<Food> _listOfFood = [];
  
  factory Cart()  => _instance;

  Cart._internal();
  
  void  addFood(Food food) {
    _listOfFood.add(food);
  }
  
  String toString() => 'Your cart contains: ${_listOfFood.join(', ')}';
}

class Food {
  final String name;
  
  const Food({required this.name});
  
  String toString() => name;
}
```

---

*Note: In Flutter, you have better ways to implement the State of your application than using a Singleton global class. Look at all the [State Management approaches](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).*

Comment: As I say in the end, note that in Flutter, you have better ways to implement the State of your application than using a Singleton global class. Look at all the [State Management approaches](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I had originally only instantiated it once. But for some reason when I try calling the "AddItem" function it always returns with the error "The method 'add' was called on null. Even after I tried taking your approach above. Yes, I was trying the Singleton method. I guess I'll try the Provider package instead.